# Pop-up in an iframe is not supporting parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have to show a web page in other web page . Iframe is the best option to do that. Everything is okay but i am facing an issue with position of popup inside iframe. 
1) I have ketp its position fixed, instead of that it is supporting scrolling. (Not in iframe scrolling but main page scrolling.)
2) it is not coming out from iframe. And not supporting main page position but iframe position. Please help.

```
  .Popup{position:fixed; top:35%;left:50%;margin-left:-100px; width: 180px: padding:10px: }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add some lines of code to get your problem easily.

Comment: I have put some popup css property which i use for popup in iframe

Comment: If you want a popup window to be outside the iframe, you should consider moving it outside the iframe.